# Assembly resolution in Unity

Tags: wcf, iis, unity-container

I have a WCF service project hosted in IIS. The main SVC file is in the root of the web application folder, and in the bin\ folder are the actual dlls. The web.config (also in the root) contains all the unity mappings. Unfortunately, it seems that because the concrete assemblies etc. are living in the bin\ folder, Unity cannot find them.

Is there a way in the Unity configuration file that one can specify a path (sort of like probing) where the DLLs might live - or to put the path inside the mappings themselves somehow? I don't want to actually have to modify the probing paths in the machine.config etc. if we can avoid that.

I've looked on MSDN and Googled around but couldn't find anything of help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with Unity having difficulties locating the assemblies under /bin? I'm asking because it should do this with no difficulty. Can you provide some more details or sample code and Unity configuration XML?

Comment: It shouldnt have a problem finding them if its setup as an Application in IIS.  Its unlikely to be a Unity issue.

Comment: Yep, in the end I realised it wasn't a unity issue, it was to do with IIS or something else - sorry, can't remember what the solution was in the end!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't a Unity issue in the end - it was more that I was trying to host the application within IIS and had to configure that correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I too doubt this is a Unity issue. Have you tried using the Fusion log viewer, FUSLOGVW.EXE, to see what the application is trying to load and where it's looking for the assemblies?

http://www.ademiller.com/blogs/tech/2008/01/gotchas-fusion-log-viewer-your-best-friend-for-assembly-load-errors/

This should tell you what the current probing path looks like and you can take it from there.